# SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations and trusted certificates

Tags: c++, c, ssl, openssl, certificate

From [SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html):

> SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations - set default locations for trusted CA certificates

Does this means I can put certificates in location (or file), which passed as parameter to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` function. And are these certificates automatically will be trusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. This is how you specify the list of certificate authorities that are trusted.